# bower i bash: bower: command not found

Tags: bower

Понадобилось доработать проект.
Клонирую к себе - `git clone ...` 
Инициализирую npm - `npm i` 
Инициализирую bower - `bower i`

И тут пишет  -

> bash: bower: command not found

Файлы: `package.json`, `bower.json`, `.bowerrc` есть.  `nodejs`, `git` - последние версии.

Работаю в `coneMu` (bash: git bush).

До этого все прекрасно работало.При чем с ноутбука все отлично запускается и работает, а вот с компьютера - нет.

Не понимаю в чем проблема. Может быть кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой. На SO пишут, что с путями что-то не так, но не пойму что и как исправить.

Comment: bower глобально установлен?

Comment: `$(npm bin)/bower`

Comment: bower и зависимости установлены в c:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\ а не в c:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm (как нужно) вот и не пойму как "перенаправить". Глобально устанавливается.

Comment: Вы вроде Sublime Text пользуетесь: [**с плагином Bower пробовали работать**](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/Kristinita/SashaBooks/blob/master/IT/Sublime%20Text/Sublime%20Text%20Power%20User.pdf#page=176)? У меня не было с ним существенных проблем. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решила так:
вручную перенесла все файлы bower с `c:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\`  в `c:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm`. Все заработало.

Answer (score 1):

> bash: bower: command not found

Шелл не может найти бинарник `bower` в папках `$PATH`.

- bower установлен локально(в проекте): `$(npm bin)/bower`
- bower не установлен:
  Это значит, что зависимость отсутствует в `package.json`

  - Установить локально: `npm i bower --save-dev`
  - Установить глобально: `npm i bower -g --save-dev`